# How to force ffmpeg to quit when stuck on a frame?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am using ffmpeg to stream an IP camera to youtube.  I believe that due to connection quality to the camera, ffmpeg sometimes gets stuck on the same frame over and over.  Like this:

frame=148491 fps= 19 q=-1.0 size= 7467667kB time=09:29:18.52 bitrate=1790.9kbits/s speed=4.26x
frame=148491 fps= 19 q=-1.0 size= 7467696kB time=09:29:47.64 bitrate=1789.4kbits/s speed=4.27x
frame=148491 fps= 19 q=-1.0 size= 7467724kB time=09:30:16.83 bitrate=1787.9kbits/s speed=4.27x
frame=148491 fps= 19 q=-1.0 size= 7467752kB time=09:30:45.95 bitrate=1786.4kbits/s speed=4.27x

Notice the frame=x is the same?  usually it keeps ticking up.

How can I get ffmpeg to simply exit when this happens?  My .sh script will restart it.  I just need it to exit.

thank you in advance!